# Insert data from Excel into oracle database using JAVA

Tags: java

I have 7 columns in my Excel sheet. I created an empty  table in database with respective column names.
So, How can I insert all the data in Excel into database table.
please help me, thanks.

Comment: Please give example data and how far you got yourself with making the code. The guildelines also specify this.

Comment: 1. read from Excell 2. put into database. What exactly problem You have?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt try it. I want full code for that.

Comment: Check out [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) for reading from excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POI to do so.Sample code is as below.For detail you can refer [this](http://thinktibits.blogspot.in/2012/12/POI-Excel-Insert-Data-to-Database-Oracle-JDBC-Example-Program.html).

```
   /* Create Connection objects */
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe", "hr", "hr");
            PreparedStatement sql_statement = null;
            String jdbc_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO XLS_POI"
                            + "(KEYWORD, TOTAL_COUNT) VALUES"
                            + "(?,?)";
            sql_statement = conn.prepareStatement(jdbc_insert_sql);
            /* We should now load excel objects and loop through the worksheet data */
            FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("xls_to_oracle.xls"));
            /* Load workbook */
            HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);
            /* Load worksheet */
            HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            // we loop through and insert data
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator(); 
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                                    switch(cell.getCellType()) { 
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: //handle string columns
                                            sql_statement.setString(1, cell.getStringCellValue());                                                                                     
                                            break;
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: //handle double data
                                            sql_statement.setDouble(2,cell.getNumericCellValue() );
                                            break;
                                    }

                            }
            //we can execute the statement before reading the next row
            sql_statement.executeUpdate();
            }
            /* Close input stream */
            input_document.close();
            /* Close prepared statement */
            sql_statement.close();
            /* COMMIT transaction */
            conn.commit();
            /* Close connection */
            conn.close();
```